# Looping through collection in collection thymeleaf

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I need to loop into collection of Points which is in Route
I have something like this:

```
<tr th:if="${routes!=null}" th:each="route : ${routes}">
            <td><span th:text="${route?.name}"> name </span></td>
            <td><span th:text="${route?.pointsForRoute}"> pointsForRoute </span></td>
            <td><span th:text="${route?.routeLength}"> routeLength </span></td>
            <td><span th:text="${route?.heightDiffrence}"> heightDiffrence </span></td>
            <tr th:if="${route.points!=null}" th:each="point : {route?.points}">
            <td><span th:text="${point?.name}"> name </span></td>
        </tr>
```

And I have got Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as each: "point : {route?.points}" (template: "show-routes" - line 41, col 51)

Route class:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
int id;

@Column(name="name")
String name;

@Column(name="points")
int pointsForRoute;

@Column(name="length")
double routeLength;

@Column(name="heightDiffrence")
int heightDiffrence;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.DETACH})
@JoinTable(name = "PunktyTrasy",
joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="idT"),
inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "idP"))
private List<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();
```

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: Please provide the controller code from which you're sending your data **routes, points** on your thymeleaf page. Is the **points** list inside the **routes** list? As I could see your fetching the points list separately from DB and on your thymleaf page you're trying to fetch the **points** list from the **routes** list.!

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the $ in the th:each="point : {route?.points}"
so replace

```
th:each="point : {route?.points}"
```

with

```
th:each="point : ${route?.points}"
```